# Why can't subclass see method of parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes.

Class A

```
public class A {

}
```

Class B

```
public class B extends A {

    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Class C

```
public class C extends B {

}
```

Class Test

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.hello(); // The method hello() is undefined for type A
    }
}
```

The code above will not compile because it reports an error that reads "The method hello() is undefined for type A"

My question is, since "a" is a `C` object, why doesn't `a.hello()` use the `hello()` method in the parent class of `B`?

If I add a hello method to `A` class, only then does the code above use the `hello()` from B class, but why do I have to add `hello()` to `A` class in order to use the method from `B` class?

Comment: Your variable `a` could contain a reference to some other subclass of `A` (like `D`) that does not provide a method `hello()` - the compiler simply doesn't know. Therefore the compiler only allows calls to methods that are defined for the class `A`.

Comment: Same as `Object o = new String("123");` and not being able to use `o.length();` However, if you cast o to a String, then you can use the methods of String.

Comment: It sounds like you might be expecting your definition of `B` to change your definition of `A`, by "extending" its functionality? Is that what you're thinking? Because, if so, that is incorrect. By defining `B` and `C`, you do nothing to `A`. Rather, `B` and `C` "copy" or "inherit" the definition of `A` as their starting point, and then anything you define in them has access to the definition of `A` also.

Comment: And then I realized I read the code wrong. `B` inherits from `A`, `C` inherits from `B` (and subsequently also inherits from `A`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is a top level class in your hierarchy. It sees only those methods that are defined within it. Methods defined by its subclasses are not accessible to `A`. Sure, you can assign `C` to variable `A`, and then you can use it wherever `A` can be used, but now `C` will be limited to methods that `A` has.

It makes sense when you think about it. When you define a type (`A`), you expect it to behave according to your definition (which does not include anything about `C` fields and methods). You do not expect it to suddenly have everything that subclasses might have defined (e.g., imagine situation where a hundred people extended your class in various ways - top class would become incredibly bloated and broad).

That is why subclasses extend parent classes - they add additional functionality that is not (and probably should not be) defined in its parent. However, the parent itself has no awareness of the additional functionality and cannot use it. Each class can only use what it has defined or its parent(s) has defined. Hence, when you assign `C` to the parent's type, you will only get those methods that `A` is aware of (but with `C`'s implementation).

Consider:

```
public class Animal {
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Walking");
    }
}


public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }

    @Override
    public void walk() {
        System.out.println("Doggy walk");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        Animal animalDog = new Dog();
        dog.walk(); // "Doggy walk"
        dog.bark(); // "Woof"
        animal.walk(); // "Walking"
        animal.bark(); // Error: bark() is not defined in the Animal class
        animalDog.walk(); // "Doggy walk"
        animalDog.bark(); // Error: Animal class has no bark()
    }
}
```

Since we assigned `Dog` to `Animal` type, it can only use methods that are defined in `Animal` class. But note that the behavior will be the one that you defined in `Dog` class for the same method.

If you must use the method and for some reason you have not assigned it to a type that has the method, you should cast it accordingly, e.g.:

```
((Dog) animalDog).bark(); // "Woof"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a bit confused on how polymorphism works. You're saying "a" is a "c" object, which is a misleading assumption that many beginners make. So here's an example to illustrate what's happening:

Say you have an "Animal" class, which is extended by a separate "Dog" class, because a Dog is an Animal. So we can write:

```
Animal someAnimal = new Dog();
```

The above statement can be rewritten as:

```
Dog someDog = new Dog();
Animal someAnimal = someDog;
```

which shows that a Dog object can be stored as an Animal object. Why? Because a Dog is an Animal. You can't do

```
Dog someDog = new Animal();
```

because an Animal is not [necessarily] a Dog.

This points back to your original assertion. Your "a" is not a "c" object because you never wrote something like:

```
C a = new A(); // sidenote : this will give you error, as you are saying the analogous Animal is a Dog
```

As a result, your superclass (which is "A") can not access methods from the subclass (which in this case is "B") because superclasses don't inherit from subclasses (it's the other way round).

Answer (score 1):

When you define `a` as an `A` type object (`A a = new C();`), it only has access to the members and methods of type `A`. To do what you want, either define `hello()` on type `A` or define `a` as an object of type `B` (`B a = new C();`). This is because the compiler is keeping track of which methods it has available. If, for some reason, you don't actually have access to the instantiation but you need to access something from `B` but it's handed to you as an `A` object, then you can cast it:

```
if (a instanceof B) (B a).hello();
else throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about variable types. You are instantiating C class, but treat result object as A. Interface of A class does not contain 'hello' method, that's why you can't use it in your example.

To solve the problem you should either add your method to A or update type of the variable to B.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable as having the type of the superclass, you can only access (public) methods and member variables of the superclass through that variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your question A is a parent class of B ,B is the parent class of C 
**(i.e. A->B->C)** and you create the object of C class through A . So, according to your program firstly it try to find the hello() method in A class because it is a super parent class of C, which is not defined hello() method that's why it shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

In method overriding  you should have same method in super class.In this scenario  most super class is A